# Problems with Symfony 2 Console task "assets:install" and Subversion

Tags: svn, symfony, assets

I'm currently developing a bundle with Symfony 2. Because I'm using windows, I have to use the command:  `php app/console assets:install web` for getting hard copies of my JS and CSS Files into the web folder.

But everytime I do that, it has Problems with my Suberversion which leads in an IOException

```
[Symfony\COmponent\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
Failed to remove file web/bundles/framework\images\.svn\text-base\open_quote.gif.svn-base
```

I did google after Problems with SVN and Symfony but only [found this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/2026) which is not really helping me.

The only way i can use the described command now is deleting the old folders, check in changes, run command, check in again. This isn't the way I want to do this. Is there any other solution?

Comment: You should svn:ignore web/bundles

Comment: this would be a working solution, but i have to check in the generated files! After testing i check them in and they will be checked out on different servers where I am unable to run the `asset:install` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: you are using old version which creates `.svn` folder inside each of your folders. Really annoying but easily solvable by simple upgrade. I use tortoise svn which creates only one .svn folder in root of project, just like git.

As I don't know shell commands for svn, you can simply right-click on `web/bundles` folder (or even on `web`) and you will get context menu with "Tortoise SVN->ignore on commit" option. After that, manually delete all files from that folder and your problem is solved.

Yep... I had the same problem and solved it this way.

UPDATE:

I just saw you need them to be checked. For that, just use an upgrade and you will not have hidden .svn folders anymore.

Comment: Upgrade Client or Server? If i have to upgrade the server version of SVN, then it is imposible for me to do that (no permission). If it is my client version: I'm using eclipse with subversive in the newest version. I would prefere an eclipse ide solution if this is possible

Comment: Eclipse has nothing to do with svn. IF you RMB over your folder using total commander or any other program, you will always get svn options. 
Any half-decent svn server company already use new version. Talk to them how to upgrade existing repository or even simpler; create new one.

Comment: +1 for your help, but i really have no chance to upgrade subversion. This isn't a public subversion host, it is my company and I have no chance to force the IT Department to upgrade... I thought there is a solution without `svn:ignore` or upgrade SVN...

Comment: because it seems to be the only solution that works, i will mark this as solution. Thanks for your help